# how can i get a detailled log to Spring Beans loading?

Tags: spring

i need a detailed log to see how spring loads my interfaces and their respective implementation classes .
i want to monitor Spring's BeanFactory's behaviour and have a look at how it manages the dependencies injections .

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a log4j.xml to your project and the appropriate JAR files.  Log to the console at INFO or DEBUG and you'll have what you want.